# is it possible to React.useState(() => {}) in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, default-value, react-hooks

is it possible to use a `function` as my React Component's state ?

example code here:

```
// typescript 
type OoopsFunction = () => void;

export function App() {
    const [ooops, setOoops] = React.useState<OoopsFunction>(
        () => console.log('default ooops')
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={ ooops }>
                Show Ooops
            </div>

            <div onClick={() => {
                setOoops(() => console.log('other ooops'))
            }}>
                change oops
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but it doesn't works ... the `defaultOoops` will be invoked at very beginning, and when clicking `change oops`, the `otrher ooops` will be logged to console immediately not logging after clicking `Show Ooops` again.

why ?

is it possible for me to use a function as my component's state ?

or else React has its special ways to process such `the function state` ?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

It is possible to set a function in state using hooks, but because state can be initialized and updated with a function that returns the initial state or the updated state, you need to supply a function that in turn returns the function you want to put in state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [ooops, setOoops] = useState(() => () => console.log("default ooops"));

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={ooops}>Show Ooops</button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setOoops(() => () => console.log("other ooops"));
        }}
      >
        change oops
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe these weren't documented in the past, but they are now. See the [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) section, as well as the yellow box above it regarding merging updates, aka using `prevState`. I also found this article helpful: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-store-a-function-with-the-usestate-hook-in-react-8a88dd4eede1

Answer (score 76):

## TL;DR

Yes, it is possible to use a function as the React Component's state. In order to do this, you must **use a function returning your function** in `React.useState`:

```
const [ooops, setOoops] = React.useState<OoopsFunction>(
    () => () => console.log('default ooops')
);

// or

const yourFunction = () => console.log('default ooops');
const [ooops, setOoops] = React.useState<OoopsFunction>(
    () => yourFunction
);
```

To update your function you also must **use a function returning your function**:

```
setOoops(() => () => console.log("other ooops"));

// or

const otherFunction = () => console.log("other ooops");
setOoops(() => otherFunction);
```

## Detailed Answer

### Notes about `React.useState`

The signature of `useState` in React with types is

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

It shows, that there are two ways to set the initial value in your state:

1. Provide the initial value as is (`React.useState(0)` - initial value `0`),
2. Provide a function, which returns the initial value to be set (`React.useState(() => 0)` - initial value also `0`).

**Important to note: If you provide a function in `React.useState`, then this function is executed, when `React.useState` is executed and the returned value is stored as the initial state.**

### How to actually store functions

The problem here is if you want to store a function as state you can not provide it as initial state as is, because this results in **the function being executed and its return value stored as state instead of the function itself**. Therefore when you write

```
const [ooops, setOoops] = React.useState<OoopsFunction>(
    () => console.log('default ooops')
);
```

`'default ooops'` is logged immediately when `React.useState` is called and the return value (in this case `undefined`) is stored.

This can be **avoided by providing a higher order function returning your function you want to store**:

```
const [ooops, setOoops] = React.useState<OoopsFunction>(
    () => () => console.log('default ooops')
);
```

This way the outer function will be definitely executed when first running `React.useState` and its return value will be stored. **Since this return value is now your required function, this function will be stored**.

### Notes about the state setter function

The state setter function's (here `setOoops`) signature is given as

```
Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>
```

with

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

Like in `React.useState` there is also the possibility to update state with a value or a function returning the value. **So in order to update state the higher order function from above has to be used as well**.

Comment: Thanks for adding this detail Peter, it was very helpful to me!

Comment: How would you execute the function you are storing in state though? You can't use call ```ooops()``` like a normal function, no?

Comment: @ANimator120 Yes, you execute it exactly like that. This is also what you can try out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers set me on the right track, but I needed to tweak my setState parameters slightly as I wanted to execute a function complete with parameters.  The following worked for me!

```
const [handler, setHandler] = useState(() => {});

setHandler(() => () => enableScheduleById(scheduleId));
```