# useCallBack and useEffect infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to the code below, I need to call a function whenever `inView` is true, but using `useEffect` and `useCallback` listing the dependencies, I cause an infinite loop. The only ways I managed to avoid it were without listing the dependencies, but I get a warning that I have to list them. I tried only with `useEffect`, but the result is the same, listing the dependencies, I have a problem with the loops. Here is the code:

```
import { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

export const useLazyLoader = (onEnterView: () => void) => {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({
    triggerOnce: true,
    rootMargin: "-200px",
  });

  const innerEnterView = useCallback(() => {
    onEnterView();
  }, [onEnterView]);

  useEffect(() => {
    inView && innerEnterView();
  }, [inView, innerEnterView]);
  return ref;
};
```

In this example, if I remove any of the dependencies to try to avoid the problem, I end up getting the warning like this:

```
Line 16:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'innerEnterView'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable reason for your infinite loop is onEnterView. To make sure that is the cause, please show us where that function is created.
What I think it happens (and I am 99.99% sure about it) is you create an arrow function in some parent (without wrapping it in useCallback). Calling onEnterView makes that parent re-render (you said you called dispatch) , which also mean the onEnterView function's reference will change. The result is you get a new onEnterView every time you call useLazyLoader hook, so the useCallback you have in place there is pretty much useless (you get a different dependency every time, so he recreates the useCallback result). To fix your problem, please wrap the onEnterView in useCallback where is defined, rather than where it is used.

Comment: feels like a broken api where the component can't control how the parent wants to pass a certain prop (memoized or unmemoized). how is the component even going to tell the parent that it needs to memoize the prop function. there is no explicit way of doing that apart from reading the docs for the child component

Comment: @gaurav5430 yeah, I agree, but at the same time, not sure what solution they could use... the main issue here is that js arrow functions have different references when recreated (even if the function itself didn't change). Probably a healthy approach would be to only use memorized functions as props.

Comment: "js arrow functions have different references when recreated" Is there a doc on this? @IonutBîrsu

Comment: @nullspace I don't think there is a specific doc on this, however, you are reinitializing a variable in there, so I expect the initial reference to not exist anymore (memory deallocation). Even if, somehow, it still exists, I doubt js would look into memory to find if your arrow function already exists, as it would be highly inefficient to do so. Also, be aware that variables used inside the arrow function might have changed, which is also quite hard to detect by js. I think you can see the arrow function just as any other object you would create inside a scope.