# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchUser'. useEffect problem?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm learning how to use `useEffect`. I encountered this warning in my react app. I tried out some solutions on SO but the warning still remains. Both `fetchUser` and `fetchPosts` trigger this warning. Can anyone enlighten me what is the problem and what does the warning mean?

App.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const getUser = async () => {
      const userFromServer = await fetchUser()
      if (userFromServer) {
        setUser(userFromServer)
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        console.log("error")
      }
    }
    getUser()
  }, [userId])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const postsFromServer = await fetchPosts()
      setPosts(postsFromServer)
    }
    getPosts()
  }, [userId])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserList = async () => {
      const userListFromServer = await fetchUserList()
      setUserList(userListFromServer)
    }
    getUserList()
  }, [])

  // Fetch user 
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  // Fetch posts
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  // Fetch list of users
  const fetchUserList = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }
```

Comment: try move const fetchUser above useEffect before it being call

Comment: Thanks! I tried but the warning is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any function or state which has been declared outside the `useEffect` then you need to pass it in the dependency array like this:

```
const someFunctionA = () => {
    ....
}

const someFunctionB = () => {
    ....
}
useEffect(() => {
    ....
}, [someFunctionA, someFunctionB])
```

You can read more about it here in case you want to know how it will be rendered: [React useEffect - passing a function in the dependency array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601538/react-useeffect-passing-a-function-in-the-dependency-array)