# React: why useState magically React.createElement when used with Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

When using `useState` hook with a `FunctionComponent` (i.e. `JSX.Element`), then React magically invokes `React.createElement()` on the component.

Though it is not a major issue, it is unexpected.

I guess it is more clear with a sample:

```js
function Test() {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useState with a component</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setComponent(Test)}>Set the state</button>

      <div>
        {component}
      </div>
      <div>
        {Test}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked, you would expect the 2 `div` elements to be rendered the same: they both *should* contain the `Test` component. But actually that's not the case: `component` contains `React.createElement(Test)`.

Here is the codesandbox to illustrate this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-with-a-component-oho5b?file=/src/index.js

I could not see anything that would detail this behavior.

My questions are:

- Is this a bug or is this a feature?
- If this a feature, can we rely on this for future versions of React?

Comment: The problem is... how the `Test` function returns when it's not invoked? Shouldn't `{Test}` be `{Test()}`?

Comment: I don't see any "issues` what that component.

Comment: I don't see any problem either. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-with-a-component-forked-3s3cs?file=/src/index.js

you call it Test() or <Test /> that works. And your state is also working.

Comment: You're attempting to render `component` in the DOM which requires React to `createElement` in order to figure out what `Test` renders to. What else would you expect `<div>{component}</div>` to do?

Comment: @ElanHamburger To be clear: React **is not** calling `createElement` automatically. Its actually not calling it at all. This is a side-effect of how `useState`'s updater works.

Comment: When JSX is converted to pure Javascript you will see createElement all over the place. The HTML like code you write is not HTML but JSX if that helps.  Just paste your JSX here and see the JS on next pane, https://babeljs.io/repl

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments I could understand what is going on: the issue is not really related to components being rendered in `useState`, but the issue is more related with `useState` used with functions. When `useState` is used with a function, the function passed to `setState` is called.

This is detailed in this question: [is it possible to React.useState(() => {}) in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621212/is-it-possible-to-react-usestate-in-react)

Comment: I'm not sure the comments are guiding people in the right direction, but you are correct. Essentially, calling the state setter with the component reference is being treated as `setState(Test())`, because `useState` accepts a function parameter to call. **Important**: this does not treat `Test` as a component with it's own lifecycle, but as a normal function that returns JSX. Storing components in state is an anti-pattern, and if your `Test` function uses hooks you will most likely get errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing this answer to add additional explanation to what is being observed here, and to make sure it is clear **why** it is happening.

The first misconception is that since `<div>{component}</div>` renders as expected, it is being converted to a `React.createElement` call. This is not the case.

### What is actually happening

The truth is that `component` already holds the returned JSX from `Test`, and does not need to be called as a function or component in order to render.

See the console logs in the snippet below for running proof of the difference.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Test() {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState();

  // Only after button has been pressed
  if (component) {
    console.log('Notice: Test has already been evaluated:', component);
    console.log('Notice: Test has not been evalutated:', Test);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useState with a component</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setComponent(Test)}>Set the state</button>
      <div>
        {component}
      </div>
      <div>
        {Test}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

For further proof that `component` has not had `React.createElement` called on it, the following snippet shows what happens if you try to use hooks within `Test`. It breaks, because `component` is not actually a React component, but simply a normal function that happens to return JSX in this case.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Test() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount');
  }, []);
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState();
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useState with a component</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setComponent(Test)}>Set the state</button>
      <div>
        {component}
      </div>
      <div>
        {Test}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It errors with "Minified React error #310" which when looked up relates to using hooks incorrectly.

### Why has `component` already been evaluated?

The key to understanding this behavior is `useState`'s [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

To access the previous state while making an update, you can pass the state updater a function - `setState((prev) => new)`. `Test` is a function, so when passing it to `setState`, React just sees that you've passed it a function and calls it in order to determine the new state - `setState(Test)` -> `setState(Test())`.

So instead of `component` holding the component reference like it may seem, it actually holds the *returned* value of calling `Test()`.

### Conclusion

- Storing component instances (or even references) in state is an anti-pattern. Hopefully now you can see why. Instead, the better practice would be to store identifiers in state and conditionally render the components based on those identifiers.
- `React.createElement` only gets called under two conditions: you use JSX syntax and it gets transpiled to `creatElement` function calls; or you call it yourself explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation! About the anti pattern, I also agree in general. Though my use case is a bit specific: I needed to handle correctly code splitting and SSR... I would have loved to use loadable-components, but sadly it is not working at all with Vite for SSR.

Answer (score 0):

A function component is a type, ok, it's a function, but you can take it as a type. So

```
function App() {
  const [Comp, setComponent] = useState();
  const onClick = () => { setComponent(Test) }

  return <div><Comp /></div>
}
```

Of course, if you want the element, you can do

```
function App() {
  const [comp, setComponent] = useState();
  const onClick = () => { setComponent(<Test />) }

  return <div>{comp}</div>
}
```

Either way is fine.

NOTE: This is a bit confusing. A function component does return all the elements, internally it'll call `createElement` before returning them. But the function component itself isn't an *DOM* element. Internally it will be attached as one special identify "fiber" to help the engine decide how to render. You can call a function component a function, because that's how the engine uses it as the fiber's `type`.