# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') while setting the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') 
Error is showing in react-dom-development.js file
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a8tF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn3EP.png
```

I am getting the above error whenever I am calling the method email handler of parent component from child component in order to set the state

**Parent component**:

```js
const loginStates = (
    function states() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }
)
    const LoginContainer = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(loginStates);

    const onChangeEmailHandler = (event) => {
        setState(prevState => {
            return { ...prevState, email: event.target.value }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <LoginComponent
                onChangeEmailHandler={onChangeEmailHandler}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child component**:

```js
const LoginComponent = props => {
    const classes = styles();
    const { onChangeEmailHandler } = props;
    const [isSignUpPage, setIsSignUpPage] = useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TextField 
              type='text' name='email' id='email' value={state.email}
              onChange={(event) =>onChangeEmailHandler(event)}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the cause for this error, it was coming because :

> <React.StrictMode>

tag was missing from *index.js* file, as soon as I wrap the  Component with
<React.StrictMode> It started working.

```
//In index.js file
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass in a function as your state, pass in the object...

```
const initialLoginState = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    
    const LoginContainer = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialLoginState);
```

Comment: I tried it but got the same error, I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error, however I made few changes to your code to make it work, it turns out that in order to pass a function in useState hook you need to pass a higher order function that returns the function you want, you can check full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621212/is-it-possible-to-react-usestate-in-react).

**Parent Component**:

```js
import LoginComponent from "./child";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const loginState = function states() {
  return {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };
};

const LoginContainer = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => loginState);

  const onChangeEmailHandler = (email) => {
    const cur = state();
    setState(() => () => ({ ...cur, email }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <LoginComponent
        onChangeEmailHandler={onChangeEmailHandler}
        email={state().email} // You need to pass the email here to display it on rerender.
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginContainer;
```

**Child Component**:

```js
import React from "react";

const LoginComponent = (props) => {
  // const classes = styles();
  const { onChangeEmailHandler } = props;
  // const [isSignUpPage, setIsSignUpPage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        id="email"
        value={props.email} // recieve the email from the props passed from parent.
        onChange={(event) => onChangeEmailHandler(event.target.value)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default LoginComponent;
```

You can check my sand box [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-booth-c4mc4?file=/src/parent.jsx)

Comment: It's showing that "TypeError: state is not a function" at   const cur = state(); I tried with const cur= state; but it lead me to the same error, Just surprised how it is working in the code sandbox

Comment: That error used to appear at first in the sand box until I passed a higher order function instead of the function directly. Anyway you already got it to work, congrats.