# How to call a callback from child environment in parent component environment passing by context in react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a prompt dialog. I register a top-level component with prompt markup. The component registers a context where I passed a few setters. In a child component, I retrieve setters from the context. The first is a variable to show the prompt the second. The second is a callback setter to be called on the agreement. I need to call a callback from the child's environment in the parent component environment. But the callback approach fails.

Two approaches on StackBlitz: [Promise](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bueac8?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/Prompt.js), and [Callback](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcrohn?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js)

The promt(parent) component.

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { Button, Dialog, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle, DialogActions } from "@material-ui/core";

export const PromtContext = createContext()

export default function ({ children }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  let handleClose = useCallback(() => { console.log('old...')})

  const setHandleClose = useCallback((callback) => {
    console.log('setHandleClose...');
    handleClose = callback
  })

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  function handleCloseClicked() {
    console.log('Clicked...', handleClose);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <PromtContext.Provider value={{setOpen, setHandleClose }}>
        <div>
          <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
            Open alert dialog
          </Button>
          <Dialog
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
              {"Use Google's location service?"}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous
                location data to Google, even when no apps are running.
              </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={e => handleCloseClicked('disagree')}>Disagree</Button>
              <Button onClick={e => handleCloseClicked('agree')} autoFocus>
                Agree
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>

        {children}
      </PromtContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}
```

The child's component uses the prompt component.

```js
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { PromtContext } from '../components/Prompt'

export default function() {

  const { setOpen, setHandleClose } = useContext(PromtContext)

  const decisionCalback = useCallback((decision) => {
    console.log('!!!OK', decision)
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('About, useeffect...', decisionCalback);
    setHandleClose(decisionCalback)
    setOpen(false)
  }, [])

  function openClicked () {
    setOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      About page.
      <Button
        onClick={openClicked}
      >Open</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

I looked for other solutions.  [Here in material-ui-confirm](https://github.com/jonatanklosko/material-ui-confirm/blob/master/src/ConfirmProvider.js), they use a promise approach. Maybe I will do the same. But now I am interested in the callback approach.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread - is it possible to React.useState(() => {}) in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621212/is-it-possible-to-react-usestate-in-react) helped to answer the question.

Because the state can be initialized and updated with a function that returns the initial state or the updated state, you need to supply a function that in turn returns the function you want to put in the state.

```js
const [ooops, setOoops] = useState(() => () => console.log("default ooops"));
```

There is [a workable stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcrohn?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js).