# How can I use mapStateToProps to access the state of user in my redux store in class component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to convert a functional component to a class component. In the functional component, I
`import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';` and can access the dispatch and user state by:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const user = useSelector(({ auth }) => auth.user);
```

Now I want to convert the component to a class component.

//userSlice.js (I omit unnecessary details)

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  role: [], // guest
  data: {
        displayName: 'xxxxxxx',
        email: 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
  },
};

const setUserInReducer = (state, action) => {
    const user = {
        data: action.payload,
        role: [action.payload.role && action.payload.role.name || 'Guest'],
    }

    return user;
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth/user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: setUserInReducer
  },
  extraReducers: {},
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

//index.js for store

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import user from './userSlice';

const authReducers = combineReducers({
  user,
});

export default authReducers;
```

In my component, how can I access the user state to use it? I have something like:

//MyComponent.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  render () {
    const user = this.props.user;
        return (
     console.log('user', user)
        )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (auth) => ({
  user: auth.user
})

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a functional component to a class component?

Comment: I was having challenge passing a function as a second argument after I update state with setState

Comment: Do you mean you had a hook like `const [state, Setstate]` and tried calling `setState(function(){ ... })` on it?

Comment: const handleToDateChange = (value) => {
    flushSync(() => {
      setToDate(value);
    });
    flushSync(() => {
      fetchData;
    });
 }

Comment: I also tried ```const handleFromDateChange = (value) => {
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {setFromDate(value)})
    .then(() => {fetchData})
 }```

Comment: There is nothing you can't do with functional components that you can do with class components. If you're hitting issues, you should ask a question about that instead. I would help you but it's been too long since I used Redux. Take a look at this question, I think this is something you might be running into: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55621212/4088472

Comment: I am actually trying to post the issue on the functional component but have to wait after 90 minutes after I posted this

Comment: @Wacademy your code looks correct, just consider that in your `mapStateToProps`, the argument you're calling `auth` is actually the entire `state` (not a specific sub-state).

Comment: I exported the userSlice as user in the auth folder index file. In the functionality components of the app, I could access user from useSelector with auth.user. But here I'm getting user is undefine in the render console